# How to merge two Mac partitions?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

Recently I ran Boot Camp Assistant to install a copy of Windows 7. The "Partitioning Disk" process froze and I force quit it - I know, bad idea - and although I was left with a functioning Mac, I noticed that the Mac is split into two separate partitions. One is 2.2 TB, and one is 801.44 GB (I have a 3 TB Fusion Drive). Previously they showed up as one single partition. When I launch Disk Utility, either from Utilities or Internet Recovery Mode, I get "The full size of the Fusion Drive is not available for repartitioning.", and I'm unable to delete/adjust either of the partitions (all the options are greyed out).

I have Time Machine and I have a separate HD backup, so I don't mind reinstalling OS X - in fact, I want to - but I want to fix the Mac hard drive so that everything appears as one cohesive partition, but I'm not sure what to do.

I found this site - http://www.rawkode.com/blog/2014/2/12/osx-fusion-drive-boot-camp-assistant-disk-utility-recovery - which seems to do what I want to do, but I'm hesitant on using "deleteVolume". I'm not sure which logical volume value to enter, and I want to ensure that if I delete a volume or whatever, I'll still be able to reinstall OS X (and if I reinstall OS X, I'd like for there to still be a Recovery Mode, just in case).

Here's a picture of my Disk Utility:

[diskutility http://www.pixelrealism.com/diskutil.jpg](http://www.pixelrealism.com/diskutil.jpg)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Disk utility upon system start up, this may increase functionality. So delete second volume and extend  Macintosh HD by dragging it down to make as a single unit. Also repair disk and permissions.

From the screenshot I noticed that you selected your boot disk, which is not possible to edit while OS is running, however second split of HD should be editable. To make less confusion, consider renaming HD, for potential data prevention while modifying HD

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I solved the issue by booting from a Mavericks USB, using `diskutil cs list`, then `diskutil cs delete` to delete the logical volume (I just used "delete", not "deleteVolume". Mac then recognized that the disk needed to be recreated and fixed it. I then did a fresh install of the OS.

Weirdly enough, I tried to install a new Boot Camp partition after the reformat, and it got stuck again at Partitioning Disk. Instead of quitting it, I just let it run. After about 45 minutes it quit, then restarted, and now my partitions are funny again, so I think it's a Boot Camp thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot from an alternative startup disk then, you could format the drive with the partitions at the top level (not down in the individual partitions).

Which would then enable you to install your new operating system to it.

[image]

The alternative startup disk could be a netboot or a different disk of any type (thumb, ssd, 2ndary HD, cd, dvd… whatever; which has a disk utility…)